# Getting libcurl Request Method from Handle

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

My app uses curl_easy_setopt in multiple places to send requests of various types through a single function that handles the actual execution and interaction with the URL.

Among other things, before the request reaches this function, the calling method has been set in one of the following ways:

- curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // FOR HEAD
- curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1); // FOR PUT
- curl_easy_setopt(connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // FOR POST
- etc.

If the call fails, I need to know what kind of call it was (e.g., HEAD, GET, PUT, POST, etc.)

Since these requests can come from anywhere in the app, the only thing I have available to me at failure time is the CURL* connection. How can I extract the call method from a CURL*? There is nothing obvious (to me) in curl_easy_getinfo.

Thanks so much for any help you might offer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## in libcurl 7.72.0 or later

Yes: use [CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_METHOD](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_METHOD.html) to extract that information.

Example:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
  CURLcode res;
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
  res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
  if(res == CURLE_OK) {
    char *method = NULL;
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_METHOD, &method);
    if(method)
      printf("Redirected to method: %s\n", method);
  }
  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
```

## before libcurl 7.72.0

No, libcurl has no way to export that information. You need to store that yourself in your application at the same time you set the libcurl options.